# S_IRUSR semantics in POSIX

Tags: linux, posix

I am learning the POSIX API, and I don't understand the logic behind some of the names.

e.g.
     `S_IRUSR`, `S_IRUSR`

What does What does the `S` stand for? I get that`R` and `W` are for read and write. But what naming convention followed by POSIX? Just like Win32 follows ***Hungarian Notation*** for naming, what does POSIX follow for their naming? For standards like POSIX, there must be documentation for it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leading `S_` is just to identify what structure/function the constant goes with.

From `<sys/stat.h>`, the constants `S_IRUSR`, `S_IWUSR`, etc are possible values for the `st_mode` member for `struct stat` (used in `stat()` and friends).  All the members of `struct stat` start with the prefix `st_`, and there are several `stat`-related macros that also start with `S_`.  The convention is merely there to make matching structure names, member names, and constants easier.

Comment: Actually the convention has another very important purpose. It prevents things like `#define mode foo` from breaking `struct stat`, etc. `st_*` is in the namespace reserved by the header. It would be much more problematic if the standard had to individually reserve each name like `mode`...

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure if they have any meaning except that they're in [`sys/stat.h`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sysstat.h.html), so the `S` may stand for "stat".

I tried doing some detective work, for example, the [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition entry for `sys/stat.h`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) says this: *First released in Issue 1. Derived from Issue 1 of the SVID.*

Then, the [Developer Specs for System V Application Binary Interface](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/) (see [Volume 1a](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/vol1a.pdf) [pdf]), page 95, and even that has names beginning with `S_`.  I haven't been able to go further back than this.

About your question in general: much of it is history.  For example, [`creat()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/creat.html) is in POSIX, but the [name comes from history](http://books.google.com/books?id=poFQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22spell+creat+with+an+e%22&dq=%22spell+creat+with+an+e%22).  Many of POSIX function names (and behavior) comes from the C standard.  In fact, their description usually have [text like](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html):

> The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the ISO C standard. Any conflict between the requirements described here and the ISO C standard is unintentional. This volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 defers to the ISO C standard.

I think the only way to find any logic behind the POSIX API is to read the history of Unix.

The following may help:

- [Unix history](http://www.princeton.edu/~hos/Mahoney//unixhistory) and links there,
- [An oral history of Unix](http://www.princeton.edu/~hos/Mahoney//unixhistory),
- [History and timeline of Unix](http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/history_timeline.html)

Answer (score 2):

Alok is correct. See [the specification for sys/stat.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html). If you were to write your own stat() / statvfs() implementation (very common in ports that make non-posix programs work on POSIX hosts) you would prefix it with something else, i.e. Z_IRUSR.

While I don't have a list handy, I am quite certain that some C implementations provide several choices for sys/stat, S_ giving you typical POSIX behavior and (X) giving you something else. I have not seen that in a long time, though, which is why I can't quite recollect where I ran into it.

Comment: You introduced that link as though it was going to back up Alok's answer, but it's the same link Alok gave, and I don't see anything in the specification saying *why* the names all start with S. Also, why would you use different names on non-Posix hosts? Wouldn't that just make the code *less* portable?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: As I noted, (now remember, we're going back to when the single UNIX specification was being hammered out) some systems implemented POSIX on top of their proprietary implementations, so you had to deliberately use POSIX to get POSIX. Hence, namespace was a factor to deal with.

You wouldn't use different names on non-posix hosts, you'd use different names ON posix hosts. I accidentally reversed that, thanks!